# R Makecluster force to use 1 thread for each core

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Can I force to use only one thread for each core? 
This is my source code,

```
cl <- makeCluster(20) #Because I have 20 available core 
foreach(i = 1:100,.combine=rbind) %dopar% {
  myFunction()
  gc()
}
```

In **myFunction** there are some operations that are multithreading (BLAS Operation). The computer that I used is shared, and someone install *openblas*, but I can't remove. Can I force to use always one thread for each core? I prefer to parallelize my code by myself and not using *openblas*.

Comment: Try using `RhpcBLASctl::blas_set_num_threads(1)` inside `foreach`.

Comment: Thank you! It works. :)